# How can we check whether sufficient amount is available in a customer's credit card in Authorize.Net?

Tags: salesforce, authorization, payment-gateway, credit-card, authorize.net

I am Working in Authorize.Net, here I have to check the customer's credit card has sufficient amount before a transaction. Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do a pre-authorization for the amount you need to charge. If it comes back approved the card has enough to cover the transaction. Just keep in mind that you'll be freezing those funds on that card so unless you release it immediately you will be causing harm to the user.

Comment: Oh... then if I void the transaction, any charges will be done?

Comment: Yes. But the owner of the merchant account will pay two transaction fees. One for the pre-auth, one for the void.

Comment: Yes. There is always a charge for every type of transaction.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this process without any transaction fee ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Any time you process a transaction of any kind a fee is charged by the processor and usually Authorize.Net, too.

Comment: :( , Anyway thank you very much for your useful information :)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy - set the transaction amount to the amount you need to clear.

Set the transaction-type to 'auth' - if you get an approval, they have the funds.  Save the auth code in your database - you'll need it later when you capture the transaction to actually get the cash

Be sure to do a capture transaction later (like when you actually ship the order) to collect the cash on the auth you did earlier.  You will need to furnish the transaction code and the auth code so they can map the capture back onto the earlier auth transaction and fund it for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. Does the amount get freezed ?

Comment: Will this process freeze the amount?